# Are there any NACA airfoils that resemble the X-29's wing?

Tags: wing, airfoil, experimental-aircraft, x-29

As a part of my project, I am trying to perform structural and aerodynamic analysis of a forward swept wing on an aircraft, specifically the [Grumman X-29](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_X-29) (pictured below).

[image]

I am assuming that information on the airfoil and wing of the X-29 is proprietary information. So, are there any open source airfoils and wing dimensions (NACA or otherwise) that closely resemble the X-29 wing?

Comment: Resources location is considered as off topic by the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You'd better ask for a specific sub problem yoyr are trying to address, the answers are likely to give you references for further reading

Comment: NASA published an ebook on the X-29: [Sweeping Forward](https://www.nasa.gov/aero/sweeping_forward.html). Have you taken a look at it already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Mason’s Perspective on the X-29](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~mason/Mason_f/AnX-29StoryV3.pdf):

> The other issue with this airfoil is that every Grumman aerodynamicist felt the need to “improve” it, so that there were many variations. I think the airfoil that was used on the X-29 was known as K-Mod 2. I’m not sure anybody can say with certainty what the actual airfoil coordinates are. Grumman was not good with
>   documentation

The airfoil appears on page 9 of that memo:

[image: X-29 airfoil drawing, from "Computational Aerodynamic Design: X-29, the Gulfstream Series and a Tactical Fighter" by Charles W. Boppe in SAE Transactions, Vol. 94, Section 6 (1985), pp. 424-468]

The reference given for it is Boppe, which I assume to mean the article ["Computational Aerodynamic Design: X-29, the Gulfstream Series and a Tactical Fighter" by Charles W. Boppe in SAE Transactions, Vol. 94, Section 6 (1985), pp. 424-468](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/44742948.pdf?seq=1).

Supposedly you can access that article in exchange for signing up with the host service, but I'm not willing to try from my current machine.